# The solution of the inequality $x^2 > b^2$, where $b < 0$ is:

Tags: inequality

Trying to learn maths as an adult and currently working my way through a high school textbook. So far, the method taught for solving quadratic inequalities has been to graph it and then read the values off the graph.

*So far, I have:* Let $x^2 = b^2.$ Then

$$x^2 - b^2 = 0 \Rightarrow (x+b)(x-b) = 0,$$
so $x = \pm b$.

The quadratic crosses the $x$ axis at $-b$ and $b$. But I get stuck when trying to graph this. I've spent a long time on it and must be missing something obvious!

Comment: You want $(x+b)(x-b)>0$, so either both factors are positive or both are negative.

Comment: If $b<0$ then $x^2>b^2$ for all $|x|>-b$ as you have already proven. While this quadratic intersects the $x$-axis at $x=0$ it never crosses it.

Comment: [Here is the case for $b=-1$](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=plot+x%5E2%3E1) to help you visualize the inequality. Happy learning.

Comment: That helped a lot, thanks Aaron.

Answer (score 0):

$$x^2>b^2\iff (x+b)(x-b)>0$$

$$\iff \Bigl((x+b)<0 \wedge (x-b)<0\Bigr) \vee \Bigl( (x-b)>0\wedge (x+b)>0\Bigr)$$
$$\iff x<b \;\text{ or } \;x>-b$$

$$\iff x\in(-\infty,b)\cup(-b,+\infty)$$
$$\iff x\in(-\infty,-|b|)\cup (|b|,+\infty)$$

Answer (score 0):

" So far, the method taught for solving quadratic inequalities has been to graph it and then read the values off the graph."

So ... the values are $-b$ and $b$.  (DOn't get confused and think $\pm b$ as written with one symbol is a single value.)

Also $b < 0$ so $-b > 0$ and so the $b < 0 < -b$ so don't get confused and assume $b$ is positive and $-b$ is negative.  Is is the exact opposite.

(If you like you could replace $b$ with $-|b|$ and $-b$ with $|b|$.

So take an $x < b < 0$ then $x^2 > b^2$ so graph that part.

Then take $b < x < -b$.  You could take $x = 0$ to make it easy.  $0^2 < b^2$ so don't graph this part.  And then if $0 < -b < x$ then $b^2 < x^2$ so graph this part.

.....

Yes,  I admit it.  $-b$ being positive throws me off too.

So let $a = -b$ so $a > 0$.

Then $x^2 = b^2 =(-a)^2 = a^2$ and

$x^2-a^2 = (x-a)(x+a)=0$ and the points are $\pm a$.  If $x < -a < 0$ then$0 < a < -x$ and $a^2 < (-x)^2 =x^2$.

And if $-a < x < a$ then $|x| < a$ and $x^2 < a^2$.

And if $0 < a < x$ then $a^2 < x^2$.

Comment: Yes, -b being positive was what was throwing me off! Am I right in thinking this is the correct way to graph? https://imgur.com/a/DWqL87z